# How can I add to the text multiple words or numbers?

Tags: unity, c#

Now I'm using {0} I add anywhere in the text in the editor {0} and it will add the random number or random word. But I want now to be able to add for example also {1} and {2} so if for example the array of words is: hello,hi,bye and I will make in the editor in the text {0}……{1} it will add randomly two words from the array like hello and hi or hi and bye. It will pick up two random words. I don't place the {0} and {1} in same place each one in other place in the text and each time it will pick two random words and will display one word at {0} and one at {1}

Same for the numbers.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CustomText : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text textField;
    public Vector2 randomRangeHours;
    public string[] words;
    public bool randomWords = false;

    private string defaultValue;
    private string originalValue;

    public void Init()
    {
        defaultValue = textField.text;
        originalValue = textField.text;
        GenerateRandomHour();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            GenerateRandomHour();
        }
    }

    private void GenerateRandomHour()
    {
        string word = "";
        if (words.Length > 0)
        {
            word = words[UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, words.Length)];
        }

        string numberName = UnityEngine.Random.Range((int)randomRangeHours.x, (int)randomRangeHours.y).ToString();

        int t = Int32.Parse(numberName);
        if (t == 1)
        {
            defaultValue = defaultValue.Replace("hours", "hour");
        }
        else
        {
            defaultValue = originalValue;
        }

        if (randomWords)
        {
            textField.text = string.Format(defaultValue, word);
        }
        else
        {
            textField.text = string.Format(defaultValue, numberName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Format` method has a `params` parameter allowing you to pass any number of arguments used to replace `{0}, {1}, {2}, ...`: `public static string Format(
 string format,
 params object[] args
)`. Example: `textField.text = string.Format("aa {0} bb {1} cc {2} dd", "word 0", "word 1", "word 2"); `

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Right so I tried this: textField.text = string.Format(defaultValue, words); and then in the editor in the Text ui in the textField where the text is in I added in two places {0{ and {1} and in the words array in the editor I added 3 words. I type the format {0} and {1} in the editor in the text in the inspector.

Comment: Then number of `args` parameters must match the number of {n} in the text.